# why the url working in web browser not loading in UIImageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Hi in my app want to display an image from url. The url is based on api response here by share a sample format https://myserver.com/:myimage.jpg
when I browse this response in web browser the image is displayed but when I try to load it in UIImageView the image is not displayed. when i remove ':' from :myimage it is working in UIImageView also. why the url working in web browser not loading in UIImageview

The following is my code

```
NSString *STR_url = @"https://myserver.com/:myimage.jpg";
    _IMG_imageVW.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:STR_url]]];
```

Working code is

```
NSString *STR_api = @"https://myserver.com/";
    NSString *STR_image_resp = @":myimage.jpg";
    STR_image_resp = [STR_image_resp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
    NSString *STR_final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",STR_api,STR_image_resp];
_IMG_imageVW.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:STR_final]]];
```

Comment: are you added the transport secirity in your app

Comment: you mean <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict> @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: yes, dataWithContentsOfURL is worked in main thread so you need wait for delay

Comment: can you print this `STR_final`

Comment: the response is STR_url in the question

Comment: is this correct `/:` or this is correct `/`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik STR_url is the API response which is working in browser STR_final is the edited one to display in image view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149772/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-jayasabeen).

Comment: try to encode your string using stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters .

Comment: @KKRocks I tried this code also

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to solve your issue.
Here is the link where you can find SDWebImageView's class file.
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

```
 NSString* UserImage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[UserFeedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"profile"]];
      UserImage = [UserImage stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
     [cell.UserProfilePic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UserImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to init using URLWithString, the parameter should be properly encoded. for example, if you want to load an online image file with spaces in the file name, you should convert it with %20. It loads in browser, because browser will do the conversion.

can try below and see - 
NSString *URLEscapedString =
[STR_url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];